# Attched Video size not set properly

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a Video object that i set like below

```
    this._VideoInput = new Video(241,241);
    addChild(this._VideoInput);
    this._VideoInput.x = 50.05;
    this._VideoInput.y = 50.05;
```

The size dimensions are perfect in Mozilla when i run the application but in IE the width of the video object expands a further 100 pixels why is this?

### EDIT

Even when i set the width 100 pixels the width size remains at 320 pixels everytime i run the application in IE

Comment: This is not related to your question, but just out of curiosity, why would you want to set the x and y position to 50.05 (instead of 50)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try look at you embedding code on the HTML side. Mess with the width and height properties, in both px and percent. If you are generating the HTML code from within Flash it's under publish settings > HTML

**EDIT**

have you tried adding a listener for the ready event, then if the width is greater than your 241 set the video's width to 241? It presumably would maintain aspect ratio by default.

Comment: the flash canvas is fine just the video object on the canvas is expanding, what the application does is that it streams live video from a red5 server, the video input is perfect just that the dimensions of the video are altered such as the width in IE even though i set the video object width to 241 pixels, the video object in IE expands to 320 pixels

Comment: @redoc01: For fellow readers at home, and my curiosity, what exactly solved your problem?